# What does different fields of nodetool cfstats mean?

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

When I am using below command.
**nodetool -h localhost -p 7199 cfstats demodb** I came up with the following results. I cant get upto any conclusion from  the following results.  I could not decide whether my two node clustered Cassandra is performing good or need  to be tuned.

```
 Keyspace: demodb
            Read Count: 81361
            Read Latency: 0.04145315323066334 ms.
            Write Count: 23114
            Write Latency: 0.06758518646707623 ms.
            Pending Tasks: 0
                    Table: schema1
                    SSTable count: 0
                    Space used (live), bytes: 0
                    Space used (total), bytes: 3560
                    SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.0
                    Number of keys (estimate): 0
                    Memtable cell count: 5686
                    Memtable data size, bytes: 3707713
                    Memtable switch count: 5
                    Local read count: 81361
                    Local read latency: 0.000 ms
                    Local write count: 23114
                    Local write latency: 0.000 ms
                    Pending tasks: 0
                    Bloom filter false positives: 0
                    Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
                    Bloom filter space used, bytes: 0
                    Compacted partition minimum bytes: 0
                    Compacted partition maximum bytes: 0
                    Compacted partition mean bytes: 0
                    Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
                    Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i see, I can tell you that your data in the table schema1 is still fully in memory "SSTable count: 0". At this point there is nothing to optimize. The statistics will be more helpful when you have more data and your in-memory state is flushed to disk. It is to early to optimize something.

Comment: hi Thanks for reply....ya your observation is  accurate . tell me from where check the number of keys in  my db and how will i know when my data will flushed from memtable to sstable. and what is this "Memtable switch count: 5 "

Comment: As soon as you get "SSTable count:" non zero you get some flushes. To force flush you can use "nodetool flush" command. 
As I understand you can't know the exact number of keys, only estimate. I can't explain the exact meaning of "Memtable switch count", need to dig deeper into Cassandra code. It seems like the Switch Count is incremented before flush, but there are also some other cases when it is switched.

Comment: Regarding the number of keys you can read here: http://planetcassandra.org/blog/counting-key-in-cassandra/ . The author explains everything quite well.